# Is it possible to use a target platform eclipse 4 with an app coded in eclipse 3?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

As the title says, I want know if it is possible to run an application coded in Eclipse RCP 3.X above an Eclipse 4.X target platform without making structural changes (such as migrating the application code to eclipse 4.X). If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse 4 still supports Eclipse 3.x RCPs using a compatibility layer.

As long as you have not used any internal interfaces you should not have much trouble upgrading.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'm gonna try out and keep you in touch

Comment: It worked very well. For those who would have the same issue, here are some useful links : http://blog.vogella.com/2011/10/11/running-eclipse-rcp-applications-in-the-e4-compatiblity-layer/, http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4MigrationGuide/article.html and http://www.modumind.com/2012/10/23/rcp-best-practices-set-up-a-target-platform/